# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in PDO and mysqli

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have tried several ways to use parameterized statements but I still keep having issues.

At first I tried parameterized statements:

```
$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=the_name", 'the_login', 'the_pass');
$query = $dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO req_form (lname, fname, email, address, city, state, zip, phone, affiliation, role, ip_address, abc, ace, carr, ema, tuac, olatc_temp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$query->execute(array($lname, $fname, $email, $addr, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $affiliation, $prof_role, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], enum($abc), enum($ace), enum($carr), enum($ema), enum($tuac), enum($last)));
```

but got "PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object"

Now I've tried:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'the_login', 'the_password', 'the_name');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO req_form (lname, fname, email, address, city, state, zip, phone, affiliation, role, ip_address, abc, ace, carr, ema, tuac, olatc_temp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('ssssssissssssssss', $lname, $fname, $email, $addr, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $affiliation, $prof_role, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], enum($abc), enum($ace), enum($carr), enum($ema), enum($tuac), enum($last));
$query->execute();
```

I still get the error, am I possibly using a reserve name in my insert statement?

EDIT (added the enum function):

```
function enum($ar){
    if(count($ar)>1)
        return 'BOTH';
    else
        return $ar;
}
```

EDIT (output of mysqli section of phpinfo():

```
mysqli
MysqlI Support enabled 
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Id: SOME_VALUE_WAS_HERE $  
Active Persistent Links  0  
Inactive Persistent Links  0  
Active Links  0  

Directive Local Value Master Value 
mysqli.allow_local_infile On On 
mysqli.allow_persistent On On 
mysqli.default_host no value no value 
mysqli.default_port 3306 3306 
mysqli.default_pw no value no value 
mysqli.default_socket no value no value 
mysqli.default_user no value no value 
mysqli.max_links Unlimited Unlimited 
mysqli.max_persistent Unlimited Unlimited 
mysqli.reconnect Off Off
```

When I put var_dump($conn) right after  the first line it prints stuff out, if I put it right above the $conn->prepare it displays NULL

Comment: This means that you aren't connected to your database.  Check your username/password.

Comment: Try checking for connection errors.  `$conn = new mysqli(...);  if ($conn->connect_error) { die($mysqli->connect_error); }`

Comment: Check if you have mysqli installed/enabled. @Rocket he's calling `new {classname}` and gets an error '{whatever} on non-object'. The only way to not get an object after `new` is either class doesn't exist or constructor throws an exception, in which case he wouldn't have gotten to the next line.

Comment: `var_dump($conn);` or `var_dump($dbc);`.. Is your object an object?

Comment: @Raymond Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of your script just after `<?php`.  Probably like Rocket said, your connection is not succeeding.

Comment: I am getting undefined variable conn, but I checked and php_mysqli.dll and php_pdo_mysql.dll is enabled

Comment: Check the output of phpinfo() - make sure PHP has recognised and initialised mysqli/PDO, just because your ini looks right will not necessarily mean they loaded correctly.

Comment: `mysqli
MysqlI Support enabled 
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Id: SOME_VALUE_WAS_HERE $  
Active Persistent Links  0  
Inactive Persistent Links  0  
Active Links  0  

Directive Local Value Master Value 
mysqli.allow_local_infile On On 
mysqli.allow_persistent On On 
mysqli.default_host no value no value 
mysqli.default_port 3306 3306 
mysqli.default_pw no value no value 
mysqli.default_socket no value no value 
mysqli.default_user no value no value 
mysqli.max_links Unlimited Unlimited 
mysqli.max_persistent Unlimited Unlimited 
mysqli.reconnect Off Off `